# Why there isn't a ReadOnlyList<T> class in the System.Collections library of C#?

Tags: c#, readonly, generic-collections

Reading about the problem of creating a read only primitive vector in C# (basically, you cannot do that),

```
public readonly int[] Vector = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // You can still changes values
```

I learnt about `ReadOnlyCollectionBase`. This is a base class for containers of objects that let their positions be accessed but not modified. Even there is an example in *Microsoft Docs*.

[ReadOnlyCollectionBase Class - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.readonlycollectionbase)

I slightly modified the example to use any type:

```
public class ReadOnlyList<T> : ReadOnlyCollectionBase {
    public ReadOnlyList(IList sourceList)  {
      InnerList.AddRange( sourceList );
    }

    public T this[int index]  {
      get  {
         return( (T) InnerList[ index ] );
      }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T value)  {
      return( InnerList.IndexOf( value ) );
    }



    public bool Contains(T value)  {
      return( InnerList.Contains( value ) );
    }

}
```

... and it works. My question is, why does not exist this class in the standard library of C#, probably in `System.Collections.Generic`? Am I missing it? Where is it?
Thank you.

Comment: Update 2015: .NET 4.5 now has ImmutableList https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), which is the generic version of the above.

You can create one from a `List<T>` directly by calling [list.AsReadOnly()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx).

Comment: This is not a true `ReadOnlyList<T>` - in the sense that you are guaranteed that the contents of the `ReadOnlyList<T>` will never change - since `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` only wraps the original list, and modifying the original list will modify the collection.

Comment: @M Kloster, but at a memory level that is true of any collection. Marking a collection as readonly is really only a suggestion to developers using the code that modifying it could result in unwanted behavior. Of course, if the collection refers to something not found in memory, then actually forcing a change would be impossible.